# Send message from content script to another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google chrome extension. My purpose is to send messages from my script1.js to script2.js. Here is what I wrote in my manifest.json:

```
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.google.fr/"],
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "js": ["script1.js"]
       
  },
  {
    "matches": ["my_website.html"],
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "js": ["script2.js"]
       
  },
```

Here is what I wrote in script1.js:

> chrome.runtime.sendMessage('hello world!!!!!!');

and in script2.js:

> chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response,sender,sendResponse){
>
> alert(response);
>
> } );

I don't think I'm doing it the right way, I think I've to use the background.js but I don't know how.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you say, you have to use background script. For example:

script1:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:"script1",message:"hello!"});
```

background.js

```
var tab2id;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.from == "script2") {
        tab2id = sender.tab.id;
    }
    if (message.from == "script1"){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab2id,message);
    }
});
```

script2.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("Script1 says: " + message.message);
});
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:"script2"});
```

Remember to include your background script in manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Comment: @FlorianBirolleau I've edited the code to show one possible way to identify the tabs.

Comment: Would you have a code to get the current tabs ID ? I'm trying to send message from another script3 to script1 and it doesn't reach script1 but it goes into the background.js. Cheers

Comment: is is possible to send `"js": ["src/scripts/content.js", "src/scripts/utility.js"]` content.js file to `utility.js` file?
both file I include on this js array